# R: efficiently select specified rows from a data.table according to another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table called dt, and another called sg, here, I want to select the subset of dt according to sg. it means in `dt`, the selected rows (both colA and colB) should be not equal to `sg` rows (both colA and colB). here is what I did:

```
dt <- data.table(colA = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), colB = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30), 
  colC = c("A", "I", "A", "A", "A", "I", "A"))
dt

sg <- data.table(colA = c(1, 3), colB = c(10, 30))
sg

dt2 <- paste(dt[, colA], dt[, colB], sep = "-")
sg2 <- paste(sg[, colA], sg[, colB], sep = "-")
dt[!(dt2 %in% sg2)]
# OR the following one
# dt[!((dt[, colA] %in% sg[, colA]) & (dt[, colB] %in% sg[, colB]))]
> dt
   colA colB colC
1:    1   10    A
2:    1   10    I
3:    1   10    A
4:    2   20    A
5:    2   20    A
6:    3   30    I
7:    3   30    A

> sg
    colA colB
1:    1   10
2:    3   30

> dt[!(dt2 %in% sg2)]
    colA colB colC
1:    2   20    A
2:    2   20    A
```

However, when the data set is big, paste operation is slow, can you help me work out an efficient method to do such substituting of a data.table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of primary keys to do the appropriate left join:

```
> setkey(dt, colA, colB)
> setkey(sg, colA, colB)
> dt[!sg]
   colA colB colC
1:    2   20    A
2:    2   20    A
```

This should be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Ritchie. That is perfect.